# What to pass as parameter to QPainter drawPoints method using PySide

Tags: python, pyside, qpainter

Using PySide, what should be the parameter to QPainter drawPoints() method?

I did not find it clear in the PySide documentation.
nor did i find an example.

Comment: If you can't find any useful docs, the better way will be open the source code! or `dir(the_module)`.

Answer (score 0):

So if you pass a string:

```
qp.drawPoints("g")
```

python will tell you that it is expecting a list.
looking at the QT C++ method you see that it is getting:

```
const QPoint* points
```

So instead of a c style array of QPoints, you need to pass a python list of QPoint's:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
  qp = QPainter()
  qp.begin(self)
  the_points = [] 
  the_points.append(QPoint(x1, y1))
  the_points.append(QPoint(x2, y2))
  qp.drawPoints(the_points)
  qp.end()
```